# EJB cannot inject other EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I do have a EJB `ActionService` which I can inject into other EJBs, that is working fine.

Now I created another EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class ActionsPerDateDataSet extends ScriptedDataSetEventAdapter  {       
    @EJB
    ActionService actionService;

@Override
public void open(IDataSetInstance dataSet) {
        actionService.foo() // However actionService is null here!
    }
}
```

Where the `ScriptedDataSetEventAdapter` comes from another framework (BIRT).
However now my `actionService` is always `null`. I can not understand why

Comment: How exactly did you inject `ActionsPerDateDataset` itself? Via `@EJB` right? Or did you manually instantiate it (or let BRIT manually instantiate it)? Regardless, where exactly are you attempting to access `actionService`? In the constructor perhaps?

Comment: And the application server is?

Comment: Glassfish v3.1. Birt is instantiating it

Comment: So you expected that manually doing `new ActionsPerDateDataSet()` would magically set all fields with a dependency injection annotation on it? That manually crafted instance is not an EJB at all. It's only a real EJB when you obtain it via `@EJB`. So basically you was attempting to inject an EJB in a plain old Java object.

Comment: If object is instantiated by another framework how EJB container can manage it? In this case it's just POJO from EJB side.

Comment: Does ActionService contains contructors without parameters? ActionService is the bean or the interface of the EJB?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the class ScriptedDataSetEventAdapter
can not be initialized in the EJB Container (First part of the cycle)
and as the initialization is not correct, the dependency injection (@EJB and @Inject) is not made.

What you could do is change the Design of your EJB and instead it's extends "ScriptedDataSetEventAdapter"
change it to a composition.

```
@Stateless
public class ActionsPerDateDataSet   {       

    ScriptedDataSetEventAdapter scriptedDataSetEventAdapter;

    @EJB
    ActionService actionService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init (){
        try {
            scriptedDataSetEventAdapter = new ScriptedDataSetEventAdapter();
        } catch( AppException e){
        }
    }

@Override
public void open(IDataSetInstance dataSet) {
        actionService.foo() // However actionService is null here!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should introduce the lib as ejbModule in ear file , so that container search the jar file and deploy it and inject it whenever it needs

Answer (score 1):

ActionService has an interface with the @local annotation or if this is a class it has to have the annotation @LocalBean.

(this to be able to access the instance of it at runtime)

In case it is an interface and if it has multiple implementations you will have to reference the implementation you need using @EJB (beanName = "nameOfImplementation") in case it is a class where @LocalBean is used to use @EJB (name = "nameEjb")

Interface with @Local
Class with @LocalBean

In the aggregation class
Interface with multiple implementations @EJB(beanName="nameOfImplementation")
Class @EJB(name="nameEjb")

note: implements an interface for ActionService with @Local and test
note: add trace the console log to know if the class is being initialized as an ejb:ActionService

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you try using CDI? I think it is worth a shot. You need to place an empty beans.xml inside your meta-inf folder and change @EJB to @Inject. But the only way this could work is if you have the external lib and your war/jar file in the same deployment unit.
2. if this does not work you will need to use JNDI for looking up your bean: 
   http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html